# How to Pass arguments to fit() using a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, iterable-unpacking

I'm trying to train a classification model on 10 different training sets, I tried using a for loop to iterate the sets names in a dictionary then pass them in fit() method in each iteration. Here is the code:

```
for n in range (1, 11):
    classifier = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=5, activation='softmax'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    X_train_value, Y_train_value = "X_train_{0}".format(n), "Y_train_{0}".format(n)
    classifier_args = {'x':X_train_value,'y':Y_train_value}
    classifier.fit(**classifier_args, batch_size=32, epochs=100)
```

but I this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

With dictionary you will have to first create a dictionary with key being the name of the variable as a string and the value being the actual variable. However, this information is already available in `vars()`, so you can use it rather then creating one.

Use `vars()`

#### sample

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_train_1 = np.random.randn(10)
X_train_2 = np.random.randn(10)
X_train_3 = np.random.randn(10)

Y_train_1 = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10))
Y_train_2 = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10))
Y_train_3 = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10))

for n in range (1, 4):
    classifier = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=5, activation='softmax'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
                       loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    classifier.fit(vars()["X_train_{0}".format(n)], vars()["Y_train_{0}".format(n)], epochs=2)
```

Output

```
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6550 - accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.6523 - accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6760 - accuracy: 0.3000
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.6737 - accuracy: 0.3000
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.5701 - accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.5681 - accuracy: 0.2000
```